# Error when entering values for a scatter fit

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph, best-fit

The code: there's a problem with the 5th line it seems, in particular with [`np.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html),

```
i = text_i.get()
r = text_r.get()
i = i.split(", ")
r = r.split(", ")        

fit = np.polyfit(i,r,1)
fit_fn = np.poly1d(fit) 
plt.plot(i,r, 'yo', i, fit_fn(i), '--k')
plt.ilim(0, 5)
plt.rlim(0, 12)
```

**Error message**

```
    fit = np.polyfit(i,r,1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 546, in polyfit
    x = NX.asarray(x) + 0.0
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types 
dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')
```

Please find what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.polyfit(x,y,1)` needs a list or array of numerical data as input for its arguments `x` and `y`. What you type in, however, is some string. So you need to split that string and convert each of its elements to a number before passing it to `polyfit`.
Try:

```
i = np.array(list(map(float, i.split(", "))))
```

Comment: I tried that, but get the following error now -------- plt.ilim(0, 5)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ilim'

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, isn't it? pyplot does not have a function called `ilim`. Since you invented this name, I cannot know what you actually wanted to do with those commands.